# Getting IPN notification with Txn_Type="recurring_payment_profile_cancel" when User has not cancelled his profile on paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, recurring-billing

Using ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus API, I changed the user profile status to cancel. It worked Fine. But I am also getting IPN notification with Txn_Type="recurring_payment_profile_cancel". User has not cancelled his profile. Did changing the status created this notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes changing the status of the profile has generated that IPN . As long as the IPN is **turn on on the PayPal account** or if **you had passed the IPN url while creating the recurring profile** , PayPal will send you the IPN for any changes on the profiles regardless of how the changes were made ( cancelled by user or by API) .